# Como puedo obtener el id de un tr?

Tags: javascript, html5

Al presionar el checkbox, se agrega la información de mi tabla principal a la secundaria.

pero al momento de de seleccionar el checkbox debería eliminarse la fila en mi segunda tabla, en este caso se elimina la ultima fila de la tabla.

como puedo obtener el id del tr, para así poder eliminar el tr que de seleccione de mi segunda tabla.

en mi programa es un while que recorre una consulta de sql, obtengo toda la información desde la base de datos. Tengo mas de 40 lineas, mi idea es seleccionar una de las filas y mandarlas a la base de datos para actualizar un campo llamado estado.

```
<script>
  var count = 0;
  function selector(codigo){
    if (codigo.checked){
      count = count+1;
      agregarFila(count);
    }else{
      count = count-1;
      eliminarFila();
    }
  }
  function agregarFila(count){
  document.getElementById("tablaprueba").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<tr id ="'+count+'"><td>'+count+'</td><td>123123</td><td>123123</td></tr>';
}

function eliminarFila(){
  var table = document.getElementById("tablaprueba");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  //console.log(rowCount);
  
  if(rowCount <= 1)
    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado');
  else
    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}
</script>
```

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>nombre</th>
    <th>precio</th>
    <th>kilos</th>
    <th>estado</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>leche</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="estado" id="estado"onClick="selector(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>pan</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="estado" id="estado"onClick="selector(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>papas</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="estado" id="estado"onClick="selector(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <table border="1" class="table" id="tablaprueba">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                    <th>USUARIO</th>
                    <th>CODIGO</th>
                    <th>KILO A PRODUCIR</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ahora mismo no estás pintando ningún ID por cada registro. Qué es lo que quieres recuperar concretamente? el ID del registro de la tabla?

Comment: puedes explicarte mejor de que  tabla quieres eliminar (usuario, codigo,kilo)? o la que le das checked?

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario crear ID por fila (TR):

- En HTML cambias el `onclick` para enviar el [evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event) como parámetro
- En la función Javascript usas el evento para saber qué [elemento lo disparó](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- Con [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) accedes a la fila y la eliminas

```js
function EliminarTR(e) {
    // e es el evento
    // e.target es el elemento que disparó el evento
    // llegas al TR con closest()
    e.target.closest('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<table id="miTabla">
  <tr id="titulo">
    <th>nombre</th>
    <th>precio</th>
    <th>kilos</th>
    <th>estado</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Id_de_la_leche">
    <td>leche</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>4</td>
<td><input type="Button" value="ELIMINAR" onclick="EliminarTR(event)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Id_del_pan">
    <td>pan</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>4</td>
<td><input type="Button" value="ELIMINAR" onclick="EliminarTR(event)" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Nota:** No es muy recomendable incluir los eventos directamente en la etiqueta HTML, es mejor obtener todos los botones en Javascript y asignarlos con [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), pero eso ya queda para que investigues.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día Matias, Bienvenido a Stackoverflow

Entiendo que estas creando de forma dinamica la tabla y quieres eliminar un registro de forma visual (re-dibujar el DOM), la mejor manera y ya que estas haciendolo de forma dinamica es colocar un id al `<tr>` y mediante una funcion onclick puedes eliminar dicho `<tr>`

Ejemplo (con una funcion onclick):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="miTabla">
  <tr id="titulo">
    <th>nombre</th>
    <th>precio</th>
    <th>kilos</th>
    <th>estado</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Id_de_la_leche">
    <td>leche</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>4</td>
<td><input type="Button" value="ELIMINAR" onclick="EliminarTR('Id_de_la_leche')" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Id_del_pan">
    <td>pan</td>
    <td>800</td>
    <td>4</td>
<td><input type="Button" value="ELIMINAR" onclick="EliminarTR('Id_del_pan')" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<script>
function EliminarTR(id_eliminar) {
  document.getElementById(id_eliminar).remove();
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

...donde dice "Id_del_pan" o el "Id_del_leche", etc (creados dinamicamente), tanto en el `<tr>` como en el **onclick**, te recomiendo que sea el **id** del producto en base de datos, para que despues cuando lo quieres eliminar se te haga mas facil identificarlo en el `SELECT` del `SQL`.